# How to Write XOR in a formula with only ors

Tags: logic

So i know that XOR can be expressed using (A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND B)
but i want to be able to express this with only using disjunction (OR) and negation is there a way to do this??

Thank you!

Comment: Without negation it will be impossible.

Comment: Sorry and with Negation @ThomasS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work: 
NOT(NOT(A OR B) OR NOT(NOT A OR NOTB))

Comment: how did you get to this answer?

Comment: I worked backwards knowing you want two trues and  two falses.A better way to do it would probably just to use De-morgan's law on the (A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND B) to change the ANDS to ORS.